# Create database with initial data in Laravel running project

Tags: laravel

I have a running project from another server. I installed it locally on my machine with an admin username and password. However, I ran a command that deleted all my database information, so it's returned to fresh databases. Is there any method to get the initial databases?

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Create Roles
        $roles = ['admin', 'instructor', 'student', 'parent', 'guest', 
            'employee', 'institute', 'candidate'];

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            Role::create(['name' => $role]);
        }
    }

    // Create user and assign admin role 
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => 'QwikTest',
        'last_name' => 'Admin',
        'user_name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@qwiktest.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('password'),
        'email_verified_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
    ]);

    $user->assignRole('admin');
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code in your question

Answer (score 0):

The command for seeding is this:

`php artisan db:seed`

or, with fresh migration:

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

Comment: i meet this  error when i run this command   
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: select * from `roles` where `name` = admin and `guard_name` = web limit 1)

Comment: Please check if your `.env` file contains the correct database ip, username and password. Maybe try logging into your mysql server using the terminal: `mysql -u username -p`

Comment: yes has correct ip DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password 
how can i use mysql -u username -p in windows ?

Comment: are you running the server with `php artisan serve` ? How have you installed mysql?

Comment: iam running docker , dbeaver as well

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd grab a full database backup from production either through workbench or phpmyadmin. Then just add that backup to your local database. No migrations to run and good data to play with.  Your admin password locally will be the same as production.